# xcolor - What is the equivalent of default text color?

Tags: color

I would like the `xcolor` color that is equivalent to the default text color in LaTeX. Is this simply `black`? Or is it some (slightly lighter) shade of grey? Perhaps surprising, I'm having trouble searching for the answer.

Comment: `xcolor` sets `color{black}` at the end, so the answer is: It's the same as `color` package, unless `black` has a different setup.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Is the default text color based on this definition of `black`, though?

Comment: I would say, they are identical. From a visual impression I could not detect any difference!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default color is black; but if you are unsure that some package might change it, it's possible to extract the one LaTeX will start with by saying

```
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}
```

since `.` refers to the current color. Then you can say `\color{defaultcolor}` to go back to the starting color.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Emulate the possible action of a package that changes the default color
\color{olive}

\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}

\begin{document}

Some text
\extractcolorspec{.}{\temp} \texttt{\meaning\temp}

\color{teal}

Some text
\extractcolorspec{.}{\temp} \texttt{\meaning\temp}

\color{defaultcolor}

Some Text
\extractcolorspec{.}{\temp} \texttt{\meaning\temp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is `\normalcolor` already, so the above isn't needed.

Answer (score 7):

The precise definition of `black` depends on the color model. Both `color` and `xcolor` load the 'default' `dvipsnam.def` file and especially `xcolor` uses

```
\definecolorset{rgb/hsb/cmyk/gray}{}{}%
 {red,1,0,0/0,1,1/0,1,1,0/.3;%
  green,0,1,0/.33333,1,1/1,0,1,0/.59;%
  blue,0,0,1/.66667,1,1/1,1,0,0/.11;%
  brown,.75,.5,.25/.083333,.66667,.75/0,.25,.5,.25/.5475;%
  lime,.75,1,0/.20833,1,1/.25,0,1,0/.815;%
  orange,1,.5,0/.083333,1,1/0,.5,1,0/.595;%
  pink,1,.75,.75/0,.25,1/0,.25,.25,0/.825;%
  purple,.75,0,.25/.94444,1,.75/0,.75,.5,.25/.2525;%
  teal,0,.5,.5/.5,1,.5/.5,0,0,.5/.35;%
  violet,.5,0,.5/.83333,1,.5/0,.5,0,.5/.205}%
\definecolorset{cmyk/rgb/hsb/gray}{}{}%
 {cyan,1,0,0,0/0,1,1/.5,1,1/.7;%
  magenta,0,1,0,0/1,0,1/.83333,1,1/.41;%
  yellow,0,0,1,0/1,1,0/.16667,1,1/.89;%
  olive,0,0,1,.5/.5,.5,0/.16667,1,.5/.39}
\definecolorset{gray/rgb/hsb/cmyk}{}{}%
 {black,0/0,0,0/0,0,0/0,0,0,1;%
  darkgray,.25/.25,.25,.25/0,0,.25/0,0,0,.75;%
  gray,.5/.5,.5,.5/0,0,.5/0,0,0,.5;%
  lightgray,.75/.75,.75,.75/0,0,.75/0,0,0,.25;%
  white,1/1,1,1/0,0,1/0,0,0,0}
```

whereas `color` uses

```
\ifx\color@gray\@undefined
  \ifx\color@rgb\@undefined
  \else
    \definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
  \fi
\else
  \definecolor{black}{gray}{0}
  \definecolor{white}{gray}{1}
\fi
```

So in both packages the definitions are the same if the color model names mean the same models then.

Since `xcolor` explicitly uses `\color{black}` at the end of the package, the textcolor is `black` then.

Comment: Can you please clarify "if the color model names mean the same models"?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, xcolor provides a quick check on the system's default color.  This system is a G5 running OSX 10.5.8, which shouldn't make a bit of difference.  But, the default color here isn't "black."

xcolor.pdf  https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en
v2.12 Dr. Kern  (11 May 2016)

pp.23-24 ¶ 2.6.4 Color testing

(borrowing your insightful code from the foregoing discussion, and using \estractcolorspecs, with the final "s":)   [*see* xcolor.pdf ¶ 2.13 pp.28-29]

> \extractcolorspecs   {(*color*)}{(*model-cmd*)}{(*color-cmd*)}
>   Extracts the color specification of (*color*) and puts it into (*model-cmd*) and
>   (*color-cmd*), respectively.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames*, x11names, svgnames, hyperref]{xcolor}

% Create some commands a la \TeX style (\LaTeX would use \newcommand)
\def\dfltColorModel
\def\dfltColor

% Get the system's default color
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}

\begin{document}

% extract the color into Model and Color
\extractcolorspecs{.}{\dfltColorModel}{\dfltColor}

Default Color Model: \dfltColorModel

Default Color: \dfltColor

\bigskip

\begin{testcolors}[rgb,cmyk,hsb,HTML,gray]
\testcolor{.}
\end{testcolors}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the `\testcolor` paragraph (p.23):

> If the column-model matches the model of the color in question, its parameters are 
>   underlined.

Here, the system's default color is "gray" "0," as confirmed by the underlining in the testcolors printout.