# Why is text turning white (possible scope leak?) after page break and listings + tcolorbox + xelatex?

Tags: xetex, listings, tcolorbox, xparse, scoping

I had a very difficult time pinning this problem down, because it only exists when certain page-breaking conditions occur.

## Problem

Text after environment mysteriously turns white under some conditions.

## Hypothesis

When embedded `listings code` within a `tcolorbox`, it is possible that the scope is lost when a page break should occur that would split that environment, but instead of page breaking, LaTeX reaches a certain penalty such that LaTeX decides to keep the environment on one page.

I have no idea how to diagnose this issue.

Let me illustrate the problem.

## Code with expected Output

This code works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%compile with xelatex
\usepackage{listings}%for mylstcode
\usepackage{xparse}%for latex3 NewDocumentEnvironemnt
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% for newtcolorbox and colorlet
\lstnewenvironment{mylstcode}[1][]{\lstset{#1,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true,basewidth=0.5em,breaklines=true}}{} % for general code
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myexample}{ O{} O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{blue!50!black} % The maximal total height of the upper and of the lower part of normal breakable tcolorboxes is about 65536pt (ca. 2300cm).
\newtcolorbox[]{myexamplebox}{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={Example: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
  breakable=unlimited,
    attach boxed title to top left,
  % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
  minipage boxed title,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
  #2
    }
\begin{myexamplebox}}
{\end{myexamplebox}\endlist}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
1
1
1
1
\endgroup
%\vspace{-1ex} % Forcefully squeeze the two environments together
\begin{myexample}[for i in \{1..40\}; do echo \$i; done]
\begin{mylstcode}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
\end{mylstcode}
\end{myexample}
Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

## Code with unexpected output

*Note that the only change is uncommenting `\vspace{-1ex}`*

This typesets, but please examine the sentences below `\end{myexample}`. You should notice that the text below the page break becomes white!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%compile with xelatex
\usepackage{listings}%for mylstcode
\usepackage{xparse}%for latex3 NewDocumentEnvironemnt
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% for newtcolorbox and colorlet
\lstnewenvironment{mylstcode}[1][]{\lstset{#1,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true,basewidth=0.5em,breaklines=true}}{} % for general code
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myexample}{ O{} O{} }
{
\colorlet{colexam}{blue!50!black} % The maximal total height of the upper and of the lower part of normal breakable tcolorboxes is about 65536pt (ca. 2300cm).
\newtcolorbox[]{myexamplebox}{%
    % Example Frame Start
    empty,% Empty previously set parameters
    title={Example: #1},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text
    % Attaching a box requires an overlay
  breakable=unlimited,
    attach boxed title to top left,
  % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
  minipage boxed title,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
  #2
    }
\begin{myexamplebox}}
{\end{myexamplebox}\endlist}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
1
1
1
1
\endgroup
\vspace{-1ex} % Forcefully squeeze the two environments together
\begin{myexample}[for i in \{1..40\}; do echo \$i; done]
\begin{mylstcode}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
\end{mylstcode}
\end{myexample}
Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.
\end{document}
```

*Note to Christian Hupfer: I know you do not like when I wrap `tcolorbox` with a `\NewDocumentEnvironment` :)*

Comment: We'll see :-P:-P:-P -- do you mean the sentences are not visible any longer?

Comment: note that `{
\colorlet{colexam}{blue!50!black} % ` puts two word spaces before the environment (which may, or may  not be relevant but beware need for `%` at ends of lines!!)

Comment: The text is only white if I use `xelatex`

Comment: Using an `external` lstenvironment while `tcolorbox` provides the same functionality is 'weird', in my point of view

Comment: I'll do a more robust testing later on, I am on my old notebook that is not really nice to work with.

Comment: may or may not be related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188174/xelatex-and-tcolorbox-incompatibility

Comment: @samcarter: It may be related, but the problem seems to exist even with `tcolorbox` 3.90. I don't say that it's a `tcolorbox` problem, however

Comment: Currently, this problem is not any longer existent on my system. I compiled both versions with `xelatex` without white lines. `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)`, `tcolorbox 2016/07/14 version 3.94`. By the way, I did nothing to achieve this, because I would not know what. I guess, `XeTeX` changed (?).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thank you for looking into this! Good to know. Perhaps I will find something in the `XeTeX` release notes. I do not know either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some strange interaction between `listings` wrapped in a `tcolorbox` and `xelatex`. I recommend to use a special `\newtcblisting` and use this (in the outer wrapper, if really needed ;-))

In this case the text does not vanish, regardless whether it is compiled with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%compile with xelatex
\usepackage{xparse}%for latex3 NewDocumentEnvironemnt
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% for newtcolorbox and colorlet

\lstnewenvironment{mylstcode}[1][]{\lstset{#1,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true,basewidth=0.5em,breaklines=true}}{} % for general code

\newtcblisting{myexamplelisting}[3][]{%
  listing only,
  listing options={#1,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true,basewidth=0.5em,breaklines=true},
  empty,% Empty previously set parameters
  title={Example: #2},% use \thetcbcounter to access the ithexample counter text
  % Attaching a box requires an overlay
  breakable,%=unlimited,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  % Ensures proper line breaking in longer titles
    minipage boxed title,
    % (boxed title style requires an overlay)
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,toprule=0pt,top=4pt,left=3mm,overlay={}},
    coltitle=colexam,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,parbox=false,boxsep=0pt,left=3mm,right=0mm,top=2pt,breakable,pad at break=0mm,
    before upper=\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname0pt, % Use instead of parbox=true. This ensures parskip is inherited by box.
    % Handles box when it exists on one page only
    overlay unbroken={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: first page
    overlay first={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]title.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: middle page
    overlay middle={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },
    % Handles multipage box: last page
    overlay last={\draw[colexam,line width=.5pt] ([xshift=-0pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0pt]frame.south west); },%
    #3%
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myexample}{ O{} O{} }
{%
  \colorlet{colexam}{blue!50!black} % The maximal total height of the upper and of the lower part of normal breakable tcolorboxes is about 65536pt (ca. 2300cm).
  \myexamplelisting{#1}{#2}%
}
{\endmyexamplelisting\endlist}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
1
1
1
1
\endgroup
\vspace{-1ex} % Forcefully squeeze the two environments together
\begin{myexample}[for i in \{1..40\}; do echo \$i; done]
\begin{mylstcode}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
\end{mylstcode}
\end{myexample}
Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.

Here is a sentence that turns white.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could not tell why the OPs code behaves odd using `xelatex`. Regarding to color management, `pdflatex` and `xelatex` produce sometimes different results. So, *do it different* is a not so bad answer ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks. The original code works with `lualatex` however. A `xelatex` bug?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am thankful for your help in offering an alternative. I must admit that I do not really like this option, because it restricts the contents of the example environment to code only. I often have a mixture of things. Losing that flexibility is a scary option, because it will affect many, many pages of documentation that I have already nicely written. :/ I wish we knew what the culprit was. If it is a `xelatex` bug, it would great to fix it! Would it be safe to add a `\color{black}` hook to the end of the tcolorbox / my wrapper as a cheap fix?

Comment: @macmadness86: If it's a `xelatex` bug, it's beyond my knowledge to fix that. I must say, however,  that your approach is actually not the best usage of capabilities. Mine is better (but not because it's by me), but since you have constructed your interface the other way round, I see that there's not much I can do from here. Try lualatex -- it works

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's difficult to say for me, if it is a `xelatex` bug. With `xelatex`, I stumble more often into color or other problems without knowing why, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269426/wrong-marginnote-positions-inside-a-tikzpicture-with-xelatex. But the reason could be that many packages are optimized for `pdflatex` (bug? incompatibility? feature?).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I think you hit the nail on the head with "optimized for `pdflatex`". I can either switch to `lualatex` or write my own verbatim environment and stop using `listings` (or stop using `tcolorbox` :/).  I have several version controlled branches containing many documents that all rely on a common compiler :/  This means I must do the latter for now, because a switch from `xelatex` would deeply affect our system and is currently too risky without more time to discover potential incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2016-09-16

Thomas F. Sturm mentions in the question comment that this problem may no longer exist, possibly due to a change in `xelatex`, but not due to a change in `tcolorbox`.

---

## Solution until Compatibility Fix

In your Preamble add the following line to **explicitly reset the font color** to black after each `tcolorbox`:

- `\AfterEndEnvironment{myexample}{\color{black}}`

Embedding `tcolorbox` **within a list** will negate the aforementioned fix outside of the list's scope. Therefore also add the following:

- `\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\color{black}}`
- `\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\color{black}}`
- `\AfterEndEnvironment{description}{\color{black}}`

Loading `xcolor` explicitly calls `\color{black}`.

**Update 2016-05-12**: Instead of explicitly setting "black", you could use `\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}` to make a `defaultcolor` colorlet that can be used after each `myexample` environment to restore the default color--at least until the packages/compiler work in harmony someday. See answers at [xcolor - What is the equivalent of default text color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278544/xcolor-what-is-the-equivalent-of-default-text-color)

---

## Related Questions

- [How do I get fontspec to work with text color white in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28305/how-do-i-get-fontspec-to-work-with-text-color-white-in-xelatex)
- [Last xe(la)tex colors text in white in some circumstances](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances)
- [xelatex and tcolorbox incompatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188174/xelatex-and-tcolorbox-incompatibility)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287580/does-tcolorbox-3-11-have-a-problem-with-page-breaks-causing-invisible-text-whit

---

## `mdframed` Approach

*Note this has a deal-breaker limitation*

It has the disadvantage that **the embedded listings environment does not properly break over pages**.

Also, I've had about as much grief as I can handle with the `listings` package. It seems to frequently cause mysterious character issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% typeset with xelatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % Add easy frames to paragraphs
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{mylstcode}[1][]{\lstset{#1,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true,basewidth=0.5em,breaklines=true}}{} % for general code

\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
hidealllines=true,
linecolor=blue!20!black,
fontcolor=blue!20!black,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
bottomline=false,
topline=false,
innerleftmargin=10pt,innerrightmargin=10,
frametitlerule=false,
frametitlerulecolor=blue!20!black,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=white,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
 firstextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                           node[] {};},%
 secondextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                           node[] {};},%
 middleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                           node[] {};},%
 singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$)
                           node[] {};},%
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myexample}{ O{} O{} }
{\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,frametitle={Example: #1}]}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myexample}[for i in \{1..40\}; do echo \$i; done]
\begin{mylstcode}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
\end{mylstcode}
\end{myexample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just FYI this apparently still an issue though, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pretext-support/BdF2p2TB9rQ